# Calling JS Function in a JS File from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

Im attempting to add markers to a google map using javascript, but the information I have is generated (TBD collected from a database).

My index.php file includes the Mapper.js script which contains the google map and functions to add the markers to the map.

The php code generates some fake stores and attempts to add them to the map using the echo $store->markerJS();

```
// generates the script code to make a google map marker
public function markerJS(){
    $s = '<script type="text/javascript">addMarker('.$this->id.",".$this->lat.",".$this->long.");</script>";
    return $s;
}
```

Mapper.js inside .../js/

```
var markers;
var map;
var bounds;

function initialize() {


    if (!(map === undefined)) {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        markers = [];
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    }


    var defaultLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(47.8258663, -122.30983839999999);
    var defaultLoc2 = new google.maps.LatLng(47.7752851, -122.3448616);
    bounds.extend(defaultLoc);
    bounds.extend(defaultLoc2);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: "Costco Lynwood",
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.8258663, -122.30983839999999)
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
            (
                    document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
            /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (input));

    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
    // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {

        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

        markers = [];
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {


            // Create a marker for each place.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location,
                addr: place.formatted_address
            });

            markers.push(marker);
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        printMarkers(markers);


    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


function printMarkers() {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        console.log("Marker " + i + ", Location: " + markers[i].addr);
    }
    console.log("End of print");
}


function addMarker(id, latitude, longitude) {

    console.log("Trying to add " + id + " to the map");
    //alert("Adding marker " + id);
    if (map === undefined) {
        console.log("Made a new map")
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        markers = [];
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    }else {
        console.log("Map defined now adding")
    }



    var latlng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: id,
        position: latlng
    });

    markers.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(latlng);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);



}


function printTo(st) {
    $('#jsOutput').text(st);
}
```

index.php (main page)

```
<html>


    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>      

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/basecss.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Mapper.js"></script>
    <div id="jsOutput">JS Output</div>


    <?php
    // put your code here
    include_once "php/Store.php";
    // Some fake markers
    $stores = [];
    // [store ID, storeTemp, outsideTemp, energy, moneyPerHour], lat, long
    $stores[0] = new Store(["526", 75, 35, 100, 20], 43.612326, -79.690479);
    $stores[1] = new Store(["510", 75, 35, 100, 20], 44.09399, -79.489758);
    $stores[2] = new Store(["524", 75, 35, 100, 20], 43.622682, -79.507152);
    $stores[3] = new Store(["512", 75, 35, 100, 20], 43.406692136925, -80.391798020282);
    $stores[4] = new Store(["535", 75, 35, 100, 20], 43.730669, -79.456223);

    foreach($stores as $s){
        echo $s." -- Adding to google maps<br>";

        // addMarker(id, latitude, longitude) JS 
        echo $s->markerJS();
    }               

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    /* 
    Document   : basecss
    Author     : nb
    Description: styles used by jQuery accordion widget
*/

root { 
    display: block;
}


/* jQuery accordion styles
----------------------------------*/
.ui-accordion { width: 100%; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header { cursor: pointer; position: relative; margin-top: 1px; zoom: 1; margin-bottom: 0; background: #eee;}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-li-fix { display: inline; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header-active { border-bottom: 0 !important; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a { display: block; font-size: 1em; padding: .3em .5em .3em .7em; }
.ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-header a { padding-left: 2.2em; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-icon { position: absolute; left: .5em; top: 20%; margin-top: -8px; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content { padding: 1em 2.2em; border-top: 1px; margin-top: -2px; position: relative; top: 1px; margin-bottom: 2px; overflow: auto; display: none; zoom: 1; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active { display: block; }



/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget { font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
.ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #b81900; background: #eeeeee; color: #333333; border-top: 0;}
.ui-widget-content a { color: #333333; }
.ui-widget-header { border: 2px solid #000000; font-weight: normal; }



/* Interaction states
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default { border: 1px solid #cccccc; background: #f6f6f6; font-weight: bold; color: #1c94c4; }
/* color of header here */
.ui-state-default a, .ui-state-default a:link, .ui-state-default a:visited { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus { border: 1px solid #fbcb09; background: #fdf5ce; font-weight: bold;color: #c77405; }
.ui-state-hover a, .ui-state-hover a:hover { color: #c77405; text-decoration: none; }
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active { border: 1px solid #b81900; background: #fffff3; font-weight: bold; color: #eb8f00; }
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited { color: #eb8f00; text-decoration: none; }
.ui-widget :active { outline: none; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
h1, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas {
    float: left;
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
}
#jsOutput {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

#phpOutput {
    float: bottom;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.controls {
    margin-top: 16px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    width: 400px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
    width: 401px;
}
.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

The php code is correctly calling the function in the javascript but it isnt adding or displaying the markers on the map?

I also get a weird error `Uncaught TypeError: a.lat is not a function`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  The PHP won't help, all that is needed is what the browser sees.

Comment: The question is about the PHP why would it not help? I have provided everything needed except the CSS., which is now added.

Comment: Because the error is coming from the API, all that is required to recreate the error is what the browser sees.  We can't run the PHP.

Comment: @EricG can you do a `var_dump` of `$s` and post it here?

Comment: Var_dump of $s inside my foreach loop is similar for each store. `object(Store)#1 (7) { ["id"]=> string(3) "526" ["storeTemp"]=> int(75) ["outsideTemp"]=> int(35) ["energy"]=> int(100) ["moneyPerHour"]=> int(20) ["lat"]=> float(43.612326) ["long"]=> float(-79.690479) } `

Comment: Added my solution to the problem. Made a work around by saving the markers i add via PHP and when the page is loading it then adds all the saved markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i was able to make a work around. Since the problem with the code was that the PHP script generation was being executed before the google maps was created due to the `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

My fix was to add a global variable which stores an array of markers to be added, so when the page is ready to go, it can then add the markers.

Heres my Mapper.js

```
var markers;
var map;
var bounds;
var ready = false;
var toAddMarkers = [];

function initialize() {



    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    markers = new Array();
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

//    var defaultLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(28.7, -127.5);
//    var defaultLoc2 = new google.maps.LatLng(48.85, -55.9);
//    bounds.extend(defaultLoc);
//    bounds.extend(defaultLoc2);
//    map.fitBounds(bounds);


    toAddMarkers.forEach(function (element, index, array) {

        console.log("Element @ " + index);
        console.log(element);
        var la = element["lat"];
        var lo = element["long"];
        var id = element["id"];

        console.log("id: " + id + "lat: " + la + "long: " + lo )

        //var latlng = {lat: la, lng: lo};
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(la, lo);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: id,
            position: latlng
        });

        markers.push(marker);
        bounds.extend(latlng);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

    });



    ready = true;

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
            (
                    document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);


    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
            /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (input));




    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
    // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {

        console.log("Search disabled");

        return;

        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

        markers = [];
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {


            // Create a marker for each place.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location,
                addr: place.formatted_address
            });

            markers.push(marker);
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        printMarkers(markers);


    });


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


function printMarkers() {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        console.log("Marker " + i + ", Location: " + markers[i].addr);
    }
    console.log("End of print");
}


function addMarker(id, latitude, longitude) {

    if (!ready) {
        console.log("1 - toAddMarkers");
        //alert("Adding marker " + id);
        var marker = [];
        marker["id"] = id;
        marker["lat"] = latitude;
        marker["long"] = longitude;
        toAddMarkers.push(marker);
    } else {
        console.log("2 - addMarker");
        var latlng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: id,
            position: latlng
        });

        markers.push(marker);
        bounds.extend(latlng);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }


}


function printTo(st) {
    $('#jsOutput').text(st);
}
```

and my index.php file

```
<html>


    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>      

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/basecss.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Mapper.js"></script>
        <div id="jsOutput">JS Output</div>

        <div id="phpOutput">PHP</div>

        <?php

        // put your code here
        include_once "php/Store.php";
        // Some fake markers
        $stores = [];
        // [store ID, storeTemp, outsideTemp, energy, moneyPerHour], lat, long
        $stores[0] = new Store(["526", 75, 35, 100, 20], 43.612326, -79.690479);
        $stores[1] = new Store(["510", 75, 35, 100, 20], 44.09399, -79.489758);
        $stores[2] = new Store(["524", 75, 35, 100, 20], 43.622682, -79.507152);
        $stores[3] = new Store(["512", 75, 35, 100, 20], 43.406692136925, -80.391798020282);
        $stores[4] = new Store(["535", 75, 35, 100, 20], 43.730669, -79.456223);

        foreach($stores as $s){
            echo $s." -- Adding to google maps<br>";
            //echo var_dump($s);
            // addMarker(id, latitude, longitude) JS 
            echo $s->markerJS();
        }               

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. Your JavaScript code runs on the user's machine in their browser. Your PHP code runs on the server.

Comment: How is it impossible. I got the php code to execute the functions in the javascript, the only problem im encountering now is that php is executing before the initialize() function in the Javascript.

Comment: php is soley server side, it can't touch your javascript.

Comment: @Coz PHP can generate javascript to run on the browser. But that is it's own concept.